# Invoke-sqlcmd failed with folloving error: Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user xxxxx

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm running this command in PowerShell:

```
$path = "F:\IFRS9-DWH\Specific\MiraBanc"
$server = "BINEW\SQLSERVER2012"
Get-ChildItem $path  -Filter *.sql -Recurse | % { $_.FullName } | Foreach-
Object {(invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $_ -serverinstance $server)}
```

It is designed to execute all .sql files, in given path. I get this error message:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user xxxxx

I'm logged on remotely to the server and running Powershell on server desktop. My user has administrator rights.

What is the problem?

Comment: You have admin rights to the server, but do you have the appropriate rights to SQL Server?

Comment: You have rights. I didn't have created user on SQL Server. Thanks